# Árbol binario de procesos con fork

Tags: c

Necesito ayuda porque estoy haciendo un programa en C en el que tengo que hacer un árbol binario de procesos usando la llamada a fork() e indicando como argumento el número de niveles del árbol.

Este sería un ejemplo de árbol binario de 3 niveles.

[image]

Por ahora tengo este código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    
    if(argc == 2) {
        int niveles = atoi(argv[1]);
        pid_t pid; 

            for(int i=0; i<niveles; i++)   {     
                switch(pid=fork()){       
                    case 0:         
                        //printf("Soy el proceso hijo: %d y mi padre es %d \n", getpid(),    getppid());       
                        break;       
                    case -1:         
                        printf("Error en la creación del proceso \n");       
                        exit(0);       
                    default:         
                        printf("Soy el proceso padre: %d \n",getpid());
                        break;     
                }   
                
                if(pid==0) { 
                    break;  //El hijo no hace nada
                }
            }
        sleep(10);
    }
    else {
        printf("El numero de argumentos es incorrecto\n");
    }
    return (0); 
}
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: El for no puede ser la profundidad, sino el ancho (es decir, cuantos hijos tendrá el nodo). La profundidad viene más por recursividad (el hijo empieza de nuevo la lógica para generar varios hijos suyos, pero esta vez con un nivel menos).

Answer (score 2):

El bucle `for` que has utilizado es un buen punto donde comenzar, pero no se comporta como quieres.

El proceso original creará `n` procesos hijos. Un hijo por iteración del bucle. Pero además, como los hijos comenzarán a ejecutarse desde el punto donde se encuentra el `fork` hacia abajo, y cada hijo llegará al final del bucle, y comenzará la siguiente iteración, completando un total de `n - 1` iteraciones, es decir, cada hijo del proceso original crea `n - 1` procesos hijos.

Por todo esto, el árbol de procesos que obtienes no es binario, sino uno con la forma del permutacional, donde cada nodo tiene un hijo menos que el padre, hasta llegar a las hojas, que no tienen hijos.

```
  +--------R--------+      // Proceso raíz (tiene 3 hijos)
  |        |        |
+-D-+    +-D-+    +-D-+    // 3 Hijos directos (tienen 2 hijos)
|   |    |   |    |   |
N   N    N   N    N   N    // 6 Nietos (tienen 1 hijo)
|   |    |   |    |   |
H   H    H   H    H   H    // 6 Hojas (sin hijos)
```

En tu caso, lo que tú quieres es que cada proceso tenga 2 hijos, por lo que no tiene que llamar `n` veces a `fork`, sino 2.

Ten en cuenta que al llamar a `fork` se copia el mapa de memoria del proceso padre en el proceso hijo, es decir, se "duplica" las variables del padre, teniendo el mismo valor que el de los hijos. Pero cuando modifiques una variable en el hijo, esta modificación no la verá el padre, porque cada uno tiene su propio mapa de memoria (lo que no se copia son las variables en memoria dinámica).

Por tanto, si tienes una variable llamada `nivel`, con un valor inicial de `n`, lo que harías es decrementar esa variable en los procesos hijos, en una unidad, y solamente llamar 2 veces a `fork`.

Además, tienes que conseguir que el padre deje de crear hijos, pero que los hijos continúen creando hijos, mientras que no sean hojas del árbol binario. Pero que cada hijo solo genere dos hijos (o uno, si cuentas al padre como nodo hermano del hijo en el árbol tras llamar al `fork`).

Si creas dos hijos con dos llamadas consecutivas, ten en cuenta que el hijo creado también querrá hacer la segunda llamada, creando un proceso más de lo deseado.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("El número de argumentos es incorrecto\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int nivel = atoi(argv[1]);
    int hijos = 0;
    pid_t proceso;

    while (nivel > 0 && hijos < 2)
    {
        proceso = fork();    // El hijo recibe 0, el padre el PID del hijo

        // Desde aquí lo ejecutan tanto padre como hijo, si fue creado
        switch (proceso)
        {
            case -1:
                printf("Error en la creación del proceso \n");
                exit(-1);
            case 0:
                printf("Soy el proceso hijo: %d y mi padre es %d \n", getpid(), getppid());
                nivel--;
                hijos = 0;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Soy el proceso padre: %d \n", getpid());
                hijos++;
        }
    }
}
```